# Reference for modern treatment of computing homology of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces by the bar construction

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, homology-cohomology, book-recommendation

I am currently reading Cartan semináire on Algebraic Topology, especially homology groups of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces. Cartan has developed a magnificient machine to compute homology groups of these space by mean of the so-called the bar construction in arbitrary coefficients; unlike his student, Serre, who used spectral sequences but these tools just work for $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficient.

In [this lecture](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1954-1955__7_1_A4_0.pdf), Cartan wrote that Maclane, in his paper, `Eilenberg-MacLane, Ann. of Math. 58, 1953, p.55-106`, proved that there is an isomorphism
$$H_{\star}(\overline{\mathfrak{B}}^{(n)}(\Lambda G)) \cong H_{\star}(K(G,n),\Lambda)$$
where $\Lambda,G,\Lambda G$ are a commutative ring with unity, an abelian group and the group ring, and $\mathfrak{\overline{B}}^{(n)}$ is the iterative bar construction. The problem of computing $H_{\star}(K(G,n))$ is therefore reduced to a purely algebraic problem. Cartan's series of lectures stress to the computational techniques rather than the aforementioned isomorphism, and MacLance's paper is written in a very old language and in my opinion, the presentation is quite difficult to me to absorb. Consequently, I would like to ask for any modern treatment of the isomorphism above, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but I learned a lot by reading Alain Clément's 2002 thesis [Integral Cohomology of Finite Postnikov Towers](https://doc.rero.ch/record/482/files/Clement_these.pdf). Clément's initial discussion of Cartan's work cites J. Milgram's 1967 paper [The Bar Construction and Abelian H-Spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256054662), Ill. J. Math. **11** (1967), 242-250. Although Milgram produces a more general construction, he does include some specific applications to EM spaces.